# xlsx and pdf got corrupted while writing by the response received from Rest api POST call

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, file, blob

Getting response from the POST api call from which getting byte[] which i am writing using output stream but xslx file getting corrupted and PDF out as blank. Belo is the common code that i use to write a file.

```
public File writeToFile(String fileName, byte[] fileContent) {
        var outputFile = new File("path", fileName);
        try (var outStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
            outStream.write(fileContent);
            outStream.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("Error writing to file: " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return outputFile;
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Code looks ok so 'fileContent' is possibly *already* corrupt

Comment: True it is, is fixed now thanks.